# How do I guarantee that a class extends an implementation in c++?

Tags: c++, generics

So say I have an interface that I want to use to specify specific properties a class should have in a container

```
class IFoo {
     virtual std::tuple<int, int> position()= 0;
     virtual std::tuple<int, int> dimension()= 0;
}
```

and I have a class that uses this interface

```
class Foo: public IFoo {
     ... implementation
}
```

and I have a container that I am creating

```
template <typename T>
class container {
      ... implementation
}
```

I want to demand that T uses the interface IFoo so that I can access the functions position and dimension of any generic object of type T. For example:

```
void container::addElement(T element){
     if(std::get<0>(element.position()) > 10){
            ... do stuff
     }
}
```

In java, it would be:

```
class container<T extends IFoo>
```

How do I do the equivalent in C++?

Comment: Which C++ standard are you using. There are several different approaches, depending on which C++ standard you are using.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am using standard 17.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using C++17, the simplest solution is to use type traits and `std::enable_if_t`:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

class IFoo {
     virtual std::tuple<int, int> position()= 0;
     virtual std::tuple<int, int> dimension()= 0;
};

template<typename T,
    typename=std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<IFoo, T>>>
class Container {

};


class Foo: public IFoo {
};

class Bar {};

Container<Foo> foo; // OK

Container<Bar> bar; // ERROR
```

And once you've updated to C++20 you can use concepts:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

class IFoo {
     virtual std::tuple<int, int> position()= 0;
     virtual std::tuple<int, int> dimension()= 0;
};

template<typename T>
concept implementsIfoo = std::is_base_of<IFoo, T>::value;

template<implementsIfoo T>
class Container {

};


class Foo: public IFoo {
};

class Bar {};

Container<Foo> foo; // OK

Container<Bar> bar; // ERROR
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This is a new project so I will simply update my standard version!

Comment: Since you are already using concept you can just use the standard concept `template<std::derived_from<IFoo>> class Container;` Don't forget to `#include <concepts>`